# jQuery - given a json response with an array like: [1, 1] [2, 3], [5,1] how to iterate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON response that returns an array like so: [1, 1] [2, 3], [5,1]

Where [project_id, unreadCount]

```
<div>
  <li id="project-1>0</li>
  <li id="project-2>0</li>
  <li id="project-3>0</li>
  <li id="project-4>0</li>
  <li id="project-5>0</li>
</div>
```

How can I use jQuery, loop through the array and update the DIV to look like this:

```
<div>
  <li id="project-1>1</li>
  <li id="project-2>3</li>
  <li id="project-3>0</li>
  <li id="project-4>0</li>
  <li id="project-5>1</li>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are all your arrays collected in one array, i.e. `[ [1, 1], [2, 3], [5, 1] ]` ?

Comment: Yes they are. Coming from a rails query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where `json` contains your JSON array:

```
$.each(json, function(i, v) {
    $('#project-' + v[0]).text(v[1]);
});
```

[`$.each()` reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var json = [ [1, 1], [2, 3], [5, 1] ];

$.each(json, function(i, value) {
    $("#project-"+value[0]).text(value[1]);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/CZsff/

Answer (score 1):

```
var array =[ [1, 1], [2, 3], [5,1]];

for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    $('div li[id$="'+array[i][0]+'"]').text(array[i][1]);
}
```